# Sopa de Letras, Recorrer Matriz

Tags: c, matrices

Buenas tardes estoy programando una sopa de letras en c++ que muestre en pantalla la matriz con todas las letras. Debo poder recorrer la matriz con las teclas de direccion y al presionar enter sobre una letra que este entre las aceptadas cambiarla de color hasta completar todas las letras de la palabra.

Me recomendaron hacerlo con sprites con dos matrices.

El problema que tengo es que no puedo recorrer la matriz y cambiar los colores de las letras que seleccione con enter.

Hice una matriz con las letras y otra con las mismas dimensiones para recorrerla.

Si alguien puede ayudarme a recorrer efectivamente la matriz, muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
char sop[10][10]={{'M','M','L','E','E','N','A','E','V','E'},
                  {'E','R','H','O','N','G','O','S','T','R'},
                  {'X','X','O','T','I','R','R','A','C','A'},
                  {'I','S','A','P','P','O','T','A','P','S'},
                  {'C','C','M','L','A','A','I','Z','O','T'},
                  {'O','A','A','U','A','N','U','L','P','U'},
                  {'S','O','M','B','R','E','R','O','M','P'},
                  {'C','N','E','A','R','R','I','I','O','O'},
                  {'W','O','J','E','N','O','C','P','Z','E'},
                  {'A','A','Z','A','A','L','N','Y','T','D'}};

char moverFlechas[10][10];
int x = 1;
int y = 1;

void main()
{
int myChar;
    int f,c,i;
    textbackground(BLACK);
    textcolor(WHITE);
    for(f=0;f<10;f++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<10;c++)
            {
                gotoxy((c+3)*2,(f+1)*2);cprintf("%c",sop[f][c]);
            }
    }

  do {
  myChar = getch();

  if (myChar == 224) {
        myChar = getch();
    } else {
            if (myChar == 72) {
            cprintf("Up Arrow");
            y=y-1;
            cprintf("x %c",moverFlechas[x][y]);
        } else if (myChar == 80) {
            cprintf("Down Arrow");
            y=y+1;
            cprintf("x %c",moverFlechas[x][y]);
        } else if (myChar == 75) {
            cprintf("Left Arrow");
            x=x-1;
            cprintf("x %c",moverFlechas[x][y]);
        } else if (myChar == 77) {
            cprintf("Right Arrow");
            x=x+1;
            cprintf("x %c",moverFlechas[x][y]);
        }

    }
  } while (myChar != 27);  //13 es enter

}
```

Comment: te faltan llaves en la lista, por cada 10 elementos pon entre llaves las letras

Comment: Gracias, hice la modificacion pero aun no lo logro. Saludos.

Comment: No termino de entender cual es tu problema.. en la consola, no se puede mover el cursor e ir escribiendo en cualquier lado... o sea... que estas tratando de mostrar y como?

Comment: Lo que tengo que hacer es mostrar primero la sopa de letras como esta actualmente. Segundo poder recorrer la matriz y si doy enter en alguna palabra que yo considere esta en las aceptadas la debo cambiar de color. En este caso una de las aceptadas es "SOMBRERO". Esto primero lo debo hacer en c++, despues en codido en 3 direcciones o intermedio y por ultimo ya con el codigo intermedio hacerlo en ensamblador TASM.

Comment: Y no la podes recorrer porque?? cual es el problema???

Comment: Con las modificaciones que hice, creo que ya puedo recorrer la matriz. Lo que no se como hacer es cambiar los colores de las letras al seleccionar con enter. Me comentaban que debo hacerlo con sprites, y colocar los valores de colores en la segunda matriz que tengo, pero no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El término **sprites** en este contexto como un arreglo definido para los posibles patrones de colores que vas a desplegar en pantalla. En base a tu descripción hay dos patrones posibles. Uno corresponde a las letras que no han sido seleccionadas. Otro patrón correspondorá a la letra seleccionada con **Enter**.

La estrategia será tener definidos, en alguna parte del programa, las acciones correspondientes (para cada patrón) para `textcolor()`y textbackground()` para cada uno de los patrones.

Asumamos que los patrones los tienes identificados como **0** y **1**, entonces, el caso mas sencillo imprimir los caracteres usando dicho patrón será:

```
if(patron == 0)  /* me gusta ser verboso */
{
    textbackground(BLACK);
    textcolor(WHITE);
    putchar(sop[fila][columna]);
}
else
{
    textbackground(BLACK);
    textcolor(RED);
    putchar(sop[fila][columna]);
}
```

Eso es por parte de los sprites. Ahora, necesitarás una matriz en donde lleves registro de cuál patrón corresponde a cada caractér, del mismo tamaño de la `sop[][]`. Supongamos que sólamente se han seleccionado los caracteres de la palabra HONGO, y quieres mostrar dichas letras en ROJO, entonces lo que tendrás (en ese momento) en este arreglo `sop_sprite_reg[][]`será lo siguiente:

```
sop_sprite_reg[10][10]={{ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  }};
```

Si ahora el usuario escoge los caracteres de la palabra LEE entonces el arreglo cambiará a lo siguiente:

```
sop_sprite_reg[10][10]={{ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  },
                        { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0  }};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marco Ramirez, excelente ayuda.